# How can i update my mysql table existing records

Tags: mysql, sql, string, sql-update

I have already this type of records.

```
PC@ABC
MAC@ABC
IPhone@ABC
```

want this type of records

```
PC
MAC
IPhone
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `substring_index()`:

```
update mytable set mycol = substring_index(mycol, '@', 1)
```